# Regex matching whole word with html element in it

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match hashtags in a string that also has html elements in it.

So I want to match # then go back to the first non-word character except when that non-word character is in a html element in which case keep going.

I started with `#[\w]*` for the basic case then tried to exclude tags with `#[\w]*(?!([^<]+)?|>)` but I'm getting no joy.

**Example**

`First #Match1 tag then another #Mat<span class="tag"></span>ch2, #<span class="tag"></span>Match3.`

**Matches**

`#Match1`

`#Mat<span id="selectionBoundary"></span>ch2`

`#<span id="selectionBoundary"></span>Match3`

Unfortunately I can't strip the html elements and the match should contain the element.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `#([\w]|(<[^>]+>))*` will do the job

Comment: @acheong87 agreed for the `<[^>]+` part. however original regex allowed empty hashtag. i've modified my answer. whether to make it capturing or not - is up to required way of using it.